# how to calculate the detection limit of a quadratic regression?

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, detection-limit

I am trying to calculate the limit of detection and quantification for an analysis method that uses a quadratic fit.

In my case, LOD and LOQ are defined as:

- **LOD**: *The limit of detection* of an analyte is the lowest concentration that can be qualitatively detected but not necessarily quantitated as an exact value.
- **LOQ**: *The limit of quantification* is the lowest concentration that can be determined with acceptable precision and accuracy.

I found formula that explain how to calculate them for a linear regression ($LOD = 3.3 * \dfrac{S_{YX}}{slope}$ where $S_{YX}$ is the standard error in estimate; same for $LOQ$ but with a factor of 10 instead of 3.3)

I have not found how to calculate these limits when using a quadratic fit. 
Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: In order to answer this, you need to supply a clear characterization of what "LOD" and "LOQ" are intended to mean.  This isn't as obvious as it might seem, because there exist dozens of distinctly different definitions of these quantities.  Exactly which ones are you applying?

Comment: I tried to detail that part, is it clearer?

Comment: I's a start, thank you.  Unfortunately those descriptions--which are characteristic of regulatory guidance (and even some regulations)--are neither quantitative nor specific.  How do you want to operationalize the concepts of "qualitatively detected" or "quantitated as an exact value"?  Those don't appear to have any statistical or scientific content.  And exactly what are your criteria for "acceptable" precision and accuracy?  Note that these are two distinct numbers, but the formula you quote contains only one number: how is it intended to relate to precision and accuracy?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. As you can see it's not really my field. I've 3 substances I'm trying to analyse and I manage to calculate the LOD & LOQ for 2 of them because the response followed a linear regression. I was thus able to use the formula written in the question to calculate them for these substances (same formula but with a different factor to get LOD and LOQ, 3.3 and 10 respectively). I calculated $S_{YX}$ as the residual standard deviation of the response.